# Not able to click on the 2nd webelement(anchor tag) in a list webelement in selenium

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Approach:- I am collecting all the IFrames and looping over them to find the particular xpath to click.
if it found it will click on that element.

Problem:- while looping to a nested IFrame i am looking for an element by xpath but i am not able to identify the element uniquely, instead it identifies 3 elements.
so i am putting it in a List..and when the xpath is identified in any frame i want to click on the 2nd link(anchor link) of the list webElement.

But it is not clicking on the link and trowing error"Element not visible".
below is the code i am using:-

```
String xPath = ".//a[@data-seclkr='1']";//xpath of 3 identified webelement
 Boolean iselementpresent = sfdc.GetWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xPath)).size()!= 0;
            if (iselementpresent==true)
            {
                System.out.println("Yes element is present in nested for case Link");
                List<WebElement> casedetails = sfdc.GetWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(".//a[@data-seclkr='1']"));
                casedetails.get(1).click();
break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("No element is NOT  present in nested for case Link");
            }
```

here is the HTML:-

```
<td class="actionColumn">
<a class="actionLink" title="Edit - Record 1 - Test FEA case" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/5000v0000018Jgj/e" data-seclki="5000v0000018Jgj" data-seclkh="294f7f9698757809b8e22aba88fe090c" data-seclke="Case" href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5000v0000018Jgj%2Fe%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D500%26retURL%3D%252F_ui%252Fsearch%252Fui%252FUnifiedSearchResults%253FsearchType%253D2%2526sen%253D500%2526sen%253Da6L%2526sen%253Da6M%2526str%253D%252509%252B02309343*%2526isdtp%253Dvw%2526isWsVw%253Dtrue%2526isWsVw%253Dtrue%2526isWsVw%253Dtrue%2526nonce%253D1e0c5b181417fcc9ba9f5c87794ccaf8671265f86f9f82afbaa70ccb35599c53%2526sfdcIFrameOrigin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fmetlifeusdirectsales--ebsdev.cs66.my.salesforce.com%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);">Edit</a>
</td>
<th class=" dataCell cellCol1 " scope="row">
<a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/5000v0000018Jgj" data-seclki="5000v0000018Jgj" data-seclkh="294f7f9698757809b8e22aba88fe090c" data-seclke="Case" href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5000v0000018Jgj%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D500%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);">02309343</a>
</th>
<td class=" dataCell cellCol2 "/>
<td class=" dataCell cellCol3 "/>
<td class=" dataCell cellCol4 ">
<a onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/5000v0000018Jgj" data-seclki="5000v0000018Jgj" data-seclkh="294f7f9698757809b8e22aba88fe090c" data-seclke="Case" href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5000v0000018Jgj%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D500%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);">Test FEA case</a>
</td>
```

I want to click on the 2nd  tag link.

Please help..

thanks

Comment: Try with By.linkText("...."), will get the specific link

Comment: Hi Grasshopper, The text is generating dynamically. can't use..